# Buttons aren't shown in the LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want that it looks so (this is a screenshot from the Graphical Layout editor):

[image]

So I created the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/clearButtonText"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:hint="@string/defaultSearchText"
            >

            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/addButtonText"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I ran my app on the emulator I saw:

[image]

When I clicked on the loupe there was still no sign of the buttons.

[image]

Comment: Add `android:weightSum="7"` (5+1+1) to the parent layout (id =controls). Are you sure you call **the same xml file** in java code?

Comment: @Rami Sorry. I just used the wrong layout file. Had two of them in the workspace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use weights for the width of the elements of your horizontal layout. This also means the width of the elements with a weight should be 0dp

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/clearButtonText"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/defaultSearchText"
        >

        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/addButtonText"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. It has helped. But the main reason was that I used the wrong layout file (setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping1);) but should use R.layout.activity_shopping. I'm new to android development.